# Setting up Eclipse for Java and PHP

Tags: eclipse

I have already installed Eclipse for Java development. I'd also like to install  Plugins for PHP, CSS/HTML and Javascript, but all the sites that I've checked only offer a 'All in one' package, so I could either download an all-in-one Java package or an all-in-one PHP package, but not both at the same time.

How do I set up my existing installation to also support PHP files?

Comment: How to set-up PHP Environment with Eclipse is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238451/help-setting-up-php-for-eclipse/16495179#16495179

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [PHPEclipse](http://www.phpeclipse.com/) which can be installed as a [regular Eclipse software update](http://www.phpeclipse.com/wiki/Installation)

The [PDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/) can also be [installed as an update](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#From_Update_Site).

For HTML/CSS etc, the [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) can be [installed in a similar fashion](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/).

Answer (score 3):

If you already have Eclipse installed, follow the instructions at [PDT Installation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#From_Update_Site) to install the PDT (PHP Development Tools). This will include the Web Tools Project (WTP), which brings editors and tools for HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

This issue made me nuts 2. First i downloaded the PDT eclipse, which would not take google plugins or apache ant. Then I downloaded the Eclipse SDK to use java ant GWT and could not load php onto it.

If you ask me, this program sucks. I like the idea, however the updates hardly ever work, and it does not support multiple coding languages like it says it does. Also the web site is shocking as it gives you 100 options to download.

Coulnt the have just made the one platform and then provided links to the plugins ???

Correct me if i am wrong guys, but trying to get PHP and Java working in eclipse is torture. Ive been stuck for 3 days now, installing and uinstalling.

One final rant, the download speeds of the eclipse servers are below 10kb, and take about half a day to install one update.

My prob is, I have to use it as the project i am working was archived with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps presented on this [installation page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation)? There is a **From update site** section in which they describe how to install it from the Software Updates menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had [this problem recently](http://www.digital-utopia.com/blogs/graham.reeds/?p=207).

I started with the J2EE Ganymede setup and added the PDT tools (via Update) afterwards.

Then I added Subclipse afterwards.

G.

Answer (score 0):

(*I wish they wouldn't change the eclipse pages all the time...*)
Look for "runtime" on the downloads page for PDT (http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/)

Why do you want JDT and PDT in one installation? I usually set up different installations for different things. It just so easy, since you don't really need to install anything. I have two setups for PDT and at least 5 for JDT.

Answer (score 0):

Install **Aptana Studio** plugin. In my experience it is much better then either PHPEclipse or PDT. However, YMMV.