# Current method for using eclipse for java and php?

Tags: php, eclipse

super easy question that i can't find the answer to on eclipse's website....

i have a new laptop and am installing eclipse on it. things seem to have a changed a bit since the 3.5 version i have on my current comp. i recall dloading eclipse just once, and then installing some plugins for stuff like php editing. but the new downloads page seems to have entirely different versions for the different languages:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

so will i need to do one install for java, one for php, one for anything else? or is the method the same as before?

thanks,
jonah

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502838/setting-up-eclipse-for-java-and-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install different development platforms onto your base Eclipse installation. Go to `Help > Install new software` and then try typing in `PDT` into the `Work with` text field. You should see it autocomplete with `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/`. If selecting it doesn't automatically populate the area below, try the `Add` button.

You should eventually see options for the `PDT SDK` that you can select to install.

See also:

- [the official installation wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation)
- [the package comparison page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php).

Comment: so should i download the java one and then install PDT onto that?  Why are there different version on the download page?  If I downloaded Eclipse for php developers, would that just be the normal eclipse with PDT preinstalled?

Comment: Take a look at [the packages comparison page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php). AFAICT, downloading just Eclipse for PHP will give you the core features + the PDT but not the [JDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JDT). So it looks like you can get either the PHP or the Java package and then install the JDT/PDT over it.